# Bash Selecting a slice of code from the file

Tags: regex, bash

I would like to select from the file a piece of code , e.g.:

```
server foo4 {    
listen {
    ipaddr = 127.0.0.1
    port = 2000
    type = auth
    }
authorize {
    update control {
            Cleartext-Password := "bob"
            }
    pap
    }
authenticate {
    pap
    }
}
```

from file where the above code does not need to have all the elements, but it must always be in the form of:

```
server foo4 { }
```

Is there a way to use regex for this or another way?

Comment: Do you need to extract that text or just detect it?

Answer (score 1):

A *hackish* way of determining this would be to say:

```
[[ $(tr -cd '{' < input | wc -c) == $(tr -cd '}' < input | wc -c) ]] && echo "Seems ok" || echo "Not ok"
```

Please note that this only determines if the count of `{` and `}` in the input file is same.  It won't work for inputs like:

```
server foo4 {    
listen {
authorize {
  }
  }
authenticate {
    pap
    }
}
```

Comment: command grep "[[ $(tr -cd '{' < input | wc -c) == $(tr -cd '}' < input | wc -c) ]]" some_file.txt 
doesn't work. How do I use this command?

Comment: @Adam Replace the word `input` in the command line with your filename.

Comment: @Adam And why are you inserting `grep`?

Comment: Ok. It's work, but when any other text will be before and after this code, it does not work

Comment: @Adam I already told you that this is a hackish way.  Maybe you can get the relevant part that you need to check and move it into another file.